# How do I ask for another position?

Tags: job-change, stress, position

I was recently hired to work at Chuck E. Cheese and it’s nice, small job for a beginner. The thing is in the interview, I told them I was open to any position except kitchen, and they still gave me kitchen. So I was wondering how would I go about asking for a different role, and I know they have other roles because they need more people working.

Comment: **I was wondering how would I go about asking for a different role** - Maybe try asking? "Are there other roles available that I could try?

Comment: Just very kindly remind them.  Franchises like that are generally perfectly helpful to employees.

Comment: Taking a page from my own industry: What have you tried?

Answer (score 5):

So a couple of things - what you can do now, and what you might consider doing next time to prevent this from happening.

### What you can do now

You need to prepare. *Always come with a solution to the problem*. This makes it easier for your boss, and the easier it is, the more likely they'll do it.

1. Do some research: Look at the other positions at your company. Talk to the people who are working them. What do they like about that position? What don't they like?
2. Decide if you want any of those positions and come up with a few compelling reasons why those positions would be a better fit for you and more beneficial to the company.
3. Go to your boss and have a frank discussion: you're interested in moving to ___ position and you feel it would benefit the company by ______.

   - If the boss says yes, great!
   - If the boss says no, then you can ask if it is "no right now" or "no forever". (It is unlikely to be "no forever") - then follow up with "what would it take for me to move to that position?" Now you have a plan. Execute the plan.

### What you need to do going forward

Don't put yourself in this position from the start! When you get a new job, be bold and decisive.

1. If you have a specific desire for a position, you need to specify that up front. "I don't want ___, ___ and ___ positions" is not a good answer, because now your future boss has to decide where to put you. "I **am** interested in ___, ___ and ___ positions" is a good answer because you've done the thinking for them.
2. If you get one of those positions you want, great!
3. If you *don't* get one of the positions you want, you have to ask
   if you are okay with the position for the foreseeable future?

   - If no, then find a new job†
   - If yes, then take the job and work on how you can move to the position you want.

† I understand you may need a job *right now* in order to eat/pay rent/etc. In that case, take the job, then start looking for a better job. Remember, this is pay in exchange for work, not friendship, and you have to take care of yourself. It is on the business to make their employees content if they want to reduce turnover.

Answer (score 1):

**I have had managers that do this on purpose.**

Not just managers, but VPs/Directors as well. The culture was "If you're comfortable, you're not growing."

Maybe they read this in a leadership book-

*“That which we need the most will be found where we least want to look.” ~ Carl Jung.*

Are they misled? Maybe. But I think this is where they may be coming from. Remember -  "And other duties as assigned" in a job description can mean anything!

Comment: Very insightful point. But what these people need to consider whether the person they subject to this has enough reserves to come through unscathed. It shouldn't need explaining how constantly being revved to maximum RPM in life can more likely than not have terrible effects.

Comment: @Levente Oh, definitely. I was in grocery logistics and folks were regularly shuffled around for no good reason other than what I described above. Someone who only had experience in dry grocery is suddenly responsible for the Perishable Warehouse. So much went undone, simply because the folks who used to do those jobs ended up somewhere else!